# Add (one below the other) and remove drop down lists (select element) inside javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, styles

I have this javascript code. It is a group of drop down lists and two buttons (Add button and Remove button).

This image is the initial display.
[image]

When I click the "Add Item" button, I want the new drop down list ("select" element) to be added below the first drop down list. Currently, it is being added to the right hand side of the buttons.

[image]

THE CODE:

```
case 'list_of_dropdowns':
          var sel = document.createElement('select');
          // ----------------------------------------------------
          //  1. SET ATTRIBUTE DISPLAY TO BLOCK
        // ----------------------------------------------------
          sel.setAttribute("display", "block");
          sel.setAttribute('id', attr_html_id);
          sel.setAttribute('onfocus', 'annotation_editor_on_metadata_focus(this)');
          sel.setAttribute('onchange', 'annotation_editor_on_metadata_update(this)');
          var option_id;
          var option_selected = false;
          for ( option_id in _via_attributes[_via_metadata_being_updated][attr_id].options ) 
          {
        var option_html_id = attr_html_id + '__' + option_id;
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.setAttribute('value', option_id);

        var option_desc  = _via_attributes[_via_metadata_being_updated][attr_id].options[option_id];
        if ( option_desc === '' || typeof(option_desc) === 'undefined' ) 
        {
          // option description is optional, use option_id when description is not present
          option_desc = option_id;
        }

        if ( option_id === attr_value ) 
        {
          option.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
          option_selected = true;
        }
        option.innerHTML = option_desc;
        sel.appendChild(option);
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        //  CODE FOR "ADD ITEM" ELEMENT
        // ----------------------------------------------------

        var add_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   // Create a <button> element
        add_btn.innerHTML = "Add Item"; 
        add_btn.onclick = function () 
        {
            //alert("Add Button is clicked");
            var sel = document.createElement('select');
            sel.setAttribute("display", "block");
            col.appendChild(sel);
        };
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        //  CODE FOR "REMOVE ITEM" ELEMENT
        // ----------------------------------------------------
        var rem_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");   // Create a <button> element
        rem_btn.innerHTML = "Remove Item";       
        rem_btn.onclick = function () 
        {
            alert("Remove Button is clicked");
        };
        
             }

         if ( ! option_selected ) 
         {
        sel.selectedIndex = '-1';
         }
            col.appendChild(sel);
           col.appendChild(add_btn);
           col.appendChild(rem_btn);
            break;
```

I tried adding the code

```
sel.setAttribute("display", "block");
```

(a) under 1. SET ATTRIBUTE DISPLAY TO BLOCK

(b) and also inside

add_btn.onclick = function () {}

But, that did not work.

---

### GOALS:

I want to do these two things:

1. On clicking "Add Item" button, the new drop down list should be added below the first drop down list.
2. On clicking the "Remove Item" button, the last drop down list (the one at the bottom or the one added most recently) should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the elements - the select item and two buttons to a div element.
To make the select elements appear below, I set the style to 'block'.

```
selectList.style.display = 'block';
```

And to remove the select item, I added this line:

`div.lastChild?.remove()`;

inside  RemoveSelect()

I put it inside an if condition so that the first three items in div (the first select item and the two buttons) are not deleted.

```
var div = document.createElement("list");
            
        var sel = document.createElement('select');
            setOptions(sel);
        div.appendChild(sel);
        var add_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON"); 
        add_btn.innerHTML = "Add Item"; 
       add_btn.addEventListener("click", AddSelect);
           div.appendChild(add_btn);

        var rem_btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        rem_btn.innerHTML = "Remove Item"; 
        rem_btn.addEventListener("click", RemoveSelect);
        div.appendChild(rem_btn);

       col.appendChild(div);
        

       function AddSelect() 
       {
              
              var selectList = document.createElement('select');
              selectList.id = 'mySelect';
              selectList.style.display = 'block';
              setOptions(selectList);

              div.appendChild(selectList);
       }

       function RemoveSelect() 
           {
         
        var x = div.childElementCount;
        if(x>3)
            {
         
             div.lastChild?.remove();
        }
       }
```